# Reduce number of columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to create a violin plot in [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html). The input is a pandas DataFrame, and it looks like in order to separate the data along the x axis I need to differentiate on a single column. I currently have a DataFrame that has floating point values for several sensors:

```
>>>df.columns
Index('SensorA', 'SensorB', 'SensorC', 'SensorD', 'group_id')
```

That is, each `Sensor[A-Z]` column contains a bunch of numbers:

```
>>>df['SensorA'].head()
0    0.072706
1    0.072698
2    0.072701
3    0.072303
4    0.071951
Name: SensorA, dtype: float64
```

And for this problem, I'm only interested in 2 groups:

```
>>>df['group_id'].unique()
'1', '2'
```

I want each `Sensor` to be a separate violin along the x axis.

I think this means I need to convert this into something of the form:

```
>>>df.columns
Index('Value', 'Sensor', 'group_id')
```

where the `Sensor` column in the new DataFrame contains the text "SensorA", "SensorB", etc., the `Value` column in the new DataFrame contains the values that were original in each `Sensor[A-Z]` column, and the group information is preserved.

I could then create a violinplot using the following command:

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="Sensor", y="Value", hue="group_id", data=df)
```

I'm thinking I kind of need to do a reverse pivot. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: could you provide some data from your dataframe?

Comment: i just added some more example data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use panda's `melt` function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'SensorA':[1,3,4,5,6], 'SensorB':[5,2,3,6,7], 'SensorC':[7,4,8,1,10], 'group_id':[1,2,1,1,2]})
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'group_id', var_name = 'Sensor')
print df
```

gives

```
    group_id   Sensor  value
0          1  SensorA      1
1          2  SensorA      3
2          1  SensorA      4
3          1  SensorA      5
4          2  SensorA      6
5          1  SensorB      5
6          2  SensorB      2
7          1  SensorB      3
8          1  SensorB      6
9          2  SensorB      7
10         1  SensorC      7
11         2  SensorC      4
12         1  SensorC      8
13         1  SensorC      1
14         2  SensorC     10
```

Comment: It looks like that creates a hierarchical index. How do I then convert that into a "Sensor" column, and still preserve the 'user_id' as well?

Comment: what's the user ID? Could you give a minimal working example in your question, showing the df and the desired output?

Comment: BTW I would also look into `panda.melt`. It seems a bit preferably to me because you can do the naming of the column in the reshaping operation itself, which seems less likely to fall prey to subtle bugs.

Comment: thanks @mwaskom, I did not know `melt`, but it seems to be exactly the way to go. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

May it's not the best way but it works (AFAIU):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'SensorA':[1,3,4,5,6], 'SensorB':[5,2,3,6,7], 'SensorC':[7,4,8,1,10], 'group_id':[1,2,1,1,2]})
groupedID = df.groupby('group_id')
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for groupNum in groupedID.groups.keys():
  dfSensors = groupedID.get_group(groupNum).filter(regex='Sen').stack()
  _, sensorNames = zip(*dfSensors.index)
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Sensor': sensorNames, 'Value':dfSensors.values, 'group_id':groupNum})
  df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Sensor  Value  group_id
0  SensorA      1         1
1  SensorB      5         1
2  SensorC      7         1
3  SensorA      4         1
4  SensorB      3         1
5  SensorC      8         1
6  SensorA      5         1
7  SensorB      6         1
8  SensorC      1         1
0  SensorA      3         2
1  SensorB      2         2
2  SensorC      4         2
3  SensorA      6         2
4  SensorB      7         2
5  SensorC     10         2
```